# Creating exact root user in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: permissions

How can I create an user which will act same as root.

1. When I login, it should go to # shell instead of $.
2. There must be no need to apply sudo before any command.
3. When I connect through Graphical ssh all folders in /home should be accessible whether the have 700 permission.

This all happen with root only by default. I want to create another account which should be able to do like root.