# Admin to root privileges

Tags: command-line, root, privileges

I'm trying to put up a CS:S([srcds](http://www.srcds.com/)) server, but when I use the given instructions, the terminal says that I don't have the permission to change it.

My account is an admin account right now. Can I give it the same privileges as root login? I want to go around the root login, and only use my admin account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you follow this guide: http://www.srcds.com/db/engine.php?id=1098643920

This guide should guide you through the installation part. You shouldn't have to install srcds as root.

(The `chmod +x hldsupdatetool.bin` is the important part)

Comment: It wont give my account root privileges, but I guess it will help me install srcds.

Comment: The guide is the correct way to install srcds. Installing and running as root is generally bad practice and should be avoided.

Comment: @EmanuelStröm there is more information about root privileges [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/262303/creating-exact-root-user-in-ubuntu-12-04/262316#262316).  How to run as **root** and why is not normally a good idea.